# Reverse Engineering a Cheat Sheet PDF

Tags: formatting, templates

I was searching for cheat sheets written in LaTeX and there is one that I like the most. There was no `*.tex` attached with the image of the `*.pdf`, however. So, I'm trying to come up with the same template myself, but I'm failing. Here's the picture of the `*.pdf` [image]

And here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.15in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        Test
        Test
    \end{multicols}
\end{landscape}
\end{document
```

Things that I can't replicate include and are not limited to font size, content wrapping in columns (if i paste lots of text between multicols, they overflow)
Ideally, I'd want to have an identical looking cheat sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.15in,landscape]{geometry} % may exceed print margins
\newcommand{\object}[2]{\textbf{#1:} #2}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}\tiny
    \begin{multicols}{2}
\object{Foo}{bar} \object{lipsum}{\lipsum}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks a lot like it! However, there's a slight problem. The font looks very odd and I'm unsure whether I'm imagining something or it really is different. I've tried removing \tiny and it looks much better now. It's as if the aspect ratio of each individual font cell is resized unproportionally, height clamped and width kept the same. Is there a different way to use smaller fonts without them looking a bit odd?

Comment: That's weird.  I don't see that at all.  `\tiny` is just there to get small letters.  You can also change the font size using e.g. `\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont` or something like that.  Or choose an entirely different font, e.g. `\usepackage{Baskervaldx}`